# Instagram app is not working when using wifi internet through out proxy server

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, proxy

In our organization we use a proxy server (Traffice Inspector) and I connect to internet usin wifi of my HTC Sensation. Most of the apps work fine except several apps that don't work at all. Say show error message that there is no internet connection at all.

How can I fix this situation please?

Comment: The only thing you can do is ask your system admin for help.The fix needs to be applied on the proxy server.